# Winform viewing

Tags: c#, winforms

Since I add an extra screen to my developpment laptop and set an extended desktop, the view of the forms change by the way it show in the picture below two form with same code in windows 8
 [image: Two winforms with same in windows 8]

Comment: Assuming the top image is on laptop display only and the bottom is with 2nd display then I would suggest that the resolution of the 2nd display is too low, so windows has dropped into a mode that doesn't support themes. What resolution are the displays?

Comment: those are runned on the same laptop at the same time

Comment: The solution of this issue is a missing  application.EnableVisualStyle();

Answer (score 2):

The lower screen is displayed in windows classic style. Your windows 8 switches from theme when you connect a extra screen to it (It could be because your pc is low on certain resources like RAM, or just because...well its Windows). You can change it back to get old default theme (howto here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/get-started-with-themes ).

Keep in mind tough that it is wise to test your form application with differed themes. You already have one control that gets pretty much useless in classic mode.

Comment: how can i change the windows theme for a visual studio project

Comment: A quick search over msdn gets me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx But I didn't get it to work on my computer (running Windows 7 in classic style). Maybe you have more luck.